# Bubble sort solution explanaition

Tags: ruby, sorting, bubble-sort

After reading online what a bubble sort is I feel that I understand it well however the solution that someone gave me was not completely intuitive.

Here is the solution to creating a method that sorts an array using the bubble sort method:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  sorted = false
  until sorted
    sorted = true
    (arr.count - 1).times do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i + 1]
        arr[i], arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1], arr[i]
        sorted = false
      end
    end
  end

  arr
end
```

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what the term "sorted" is doing here. I know there is a .sort method but I could not find any sorted method and it is not entirely clear how the loop knows how to end.

Can someone explain a little bit more what is happening with the term "sorted"?

Comment: it's a variable. not a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sorted` is a Boolean variable that is used to indicate whether the sort is complete or not.

Initially, `sorted` is set to false (assuming that the array is not yet sorted).  The entry condition on the main (outer) loop checks whether `sorted` is true or false, and, as you can see, the loop continues until `sorted` is true.

Each time through the outer loop, `sorted` starts off being set to true.  But then the inner loop checks if there are any values in the array that are not in the correct sequence, and swaps them if they are not, and sets `sorted` to false.

Only when the inner loop iterates through the entire array without needing to swap any values does `sorted` remain true and the outer loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a method, it is a local variable. Particularly, these types of variables are called flags. It switches between a relatively small number of alternative values to keep the inner state of an algorithm. In this case, it switches between `false` and `true`, and is used to control whether to escape from the `until` loop or not.